# How do I make a grid of square buttons in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

I am working on making a copy of the game Minesweeper for a project at school. I am currently working on how to make the GUI for the game, and am moving away from the Python graphics library, and towards Tkinter for my need to have a clickable interface. The game is comprised of a 9x9 grid of squares, which I am trying to make out of (square) buttons. I was able to comprise a 9x9 grid of squares, but am struggling as to how to make each of said buttons square. Eventually, I am thinking of adding photos on top of the buttons, but just want to get the grid worked out first.

EDIT: The images I will be using will be 60px wide. One example - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZXu0.jpg

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button
from functools import partial

root = Tk()
root.title(string="Minesweeper")

def btn_click(i):
    print(f"clicked {i}")


# Layout for Numpad
btns_frame = Frame(root)
btns_frame.pack()
all_locations = (['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9'], ['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b9'], ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9',], 
['d1','d2','d3','d4','d5','d6','d7','d8','d9',], ['e1','e2','e3','e4','e5','e6','e7','e8','e9',], ['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7','f8','f9',], 
['g1','g2','g3','g4','g5','g6','g7','g8','g9',], ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','h7','h8','h9',], ['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5','i6','i7','i8','i9'])
for row in range(len(all_locations)):
    for col in range(len(all_locations[row])):
        i = all_locations[row][col]
        b = Button(btns_frame, text=str(i), command=partial(btn_click, i))
        b.grid(row=row + 1, column=col)

root.mainloop()
```

I have the grid laid out with the columns being (a - i), and rows being (1 - 9), and will be using these values to add to a continuously updating dictionary to determine where the bombs are, and what has been clicked.

Comment: If you going to use images on the buttons, then you can specify the same value for `width` and `height` options when image is used.

Comment: Since the linked image has same width and height, you can simply use it on the buttons and the buttons will be square.